# Why does the sum of the squares of $k$ standard normal distributions become skewed?

Tags: statistics

Why does the sum of the squares of $k$ standard normal distributions become skewed?

Let $z_1,....z_k$ be independent random variables with standard normal distributions.

Then $z_1^2+...+z_k^2$ has a chi-square distribution with k degree's of freedom, which is skewed. All of the $z_i$ as symmetric, how is the sum of their squares skewed? Why is it skewed right and not left?

Thank you.

Comment: But $z_i^{\color{red}2} $ is not symmetric.

Comment: $|z_i|$ (a half-normal distribution) is clearly right skewed, so it is not a surprise that $|z_i|^2$ is even more right skewed, but that is equal to $z_i^2$.  Sums of independent versions of these will than also be right skewed (though less so so to Central Limit Theorem effects)

Comment: Random variables that are truncated from below or above often possess skewed distributions. The skewness is usually directed away from the truncated value. The sum of the squares of $n$ iid normal distributions will always be $\geq 0$ i.e. is truncated at $0$. If its expected value is "close" to the truncated value, this distribution will probably be skewed right. This isn't always the case, but it's still good to keep in mind.